# react router link not shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've wanted to add a react router link to the modal in my app. when I click on the modal, the id doesn't show immediately in the url. The modal id is shown in the url only after I close the modal. Also when I reload the page with the modal open, I want that the modal be still open but the modal closes if I refresh the page but the modal id is still in the url so that doesn't look good. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  }
};

Modal.setAppElement("#root");
const ListItem = ({ photo }) => {
  console.log(photo.links.download_location);
  const downloadImage = () => {};
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div key={photo.id} className="grid__item card">
          <div className="card__body">
            <img
              src={photo.urls.small}
              alt=""
              onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Link to={`/${photo.id}`}>
          <Modal
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}
            style={customStyles}
          >
            <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} className="button">
                Close
              </button>
              <button onClick={downloadImage()}>Download</button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        </Link>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
export default ListItem;
```

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/embed/competent-keller-jjuiq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Yusufbek that doesn't look like what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In order to show modal after refreshing the page, you need to save your isModalOpen state in browser localstorage.

Comment: I don't know how to use localstorage. can you show me how to do it in my sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-murdock-2riih?file=/src/ListItem.js

Comment: I don't think you need to use localStorage

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit damp-rain-8bqrp]

You need to wrap each image with the Link component. And then create Route to render the Modal.

Comment: wow this solution is the closest for the result i want. but there is a problem that when I refresh with the modal open, then there is an error. how to get rid of that error? it says `photo is undefined`

Comment: You have to use context or refetch the photo according to the id provided in the URL in the modal wrapper in order to get the result you want.

Comment: Currently, `photo` is available via state property of the location. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: so that's not possible to load the modal even after refresh?

Comment: It is possible but you should not use the location state to get the clicked photo. What you need to do is refetch the photo according to the given id in the Modal.

Comment: Look into Link component's `to` prop.

Comment: can you please show me how to do it? I can't understand it properly. please

Comment: that id is generated dynamically  so how to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219193/discussion-between-yusufbek-and-gonnabefireifnohelp).